# Scraping data from the tag names in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to scrape user data from a website. I need User ID which are available in the tag names itself.I am trying to scrape the UID using python selenium and beautiful soup in the **div** tag.

Example:

```
<"div id="UID_**60CE07D6DF5C02A987ED7B076F4154F3**-SRC_328619641" class="memberOverlayLink" onmouseover="ta.trackEventOnPage('Reviews','show_reviewer_info_window','user_name_photo'); ta.call('ta.overlays.Factory.memberOverlayWOffset', event, this, 's3 dg rgba_gry update2012', 0, (new Element(this)).getElement('.avatar')&amp;&amp;(new Element(this)).getElement('.avatar').getStyle('border-radius')=='100%'?-10:0);">
```

I am trying to scrape the UID using python selenium and beautiful soup in the div tag . I have looked through all the documentation and several web pages but I can't find a solution for this. If anyone can please tell me if such a thing is possible I would be very grateful.

Comment: *"I have looked through all the documentation and several web pages but I can't find a solution for this."* - That is pretty unlikely. If the first half of the statement is true, then the second half can't be true. Or the other way around. In any case, if you really tried, you should have some code to show.

Comment: @Tomalak- Both the statements are true I am new to web scraping so I guess I don't know the right places I should have been looking at. The small code that I could come up with was- 


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g147417-d507175-Reviews-Atlantis_Royal_Towers_Autograph_Collection-Paradise_Island_New_Providence_Island_Bahama.html#REVIEWS")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
for link in soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"memberOverlayLink"}):
    link.get("id")
print(link);

Comment: but it was giving me way more data then I needed

Comment: Please don't post code into the comments. Edit your question directly. My comment was intended to encourage you to post the code you have so far, so people can see what you tried, which makes it easier to show you the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the `id` attribute value is always in the format `UID_` followed by one or more alphanumeric characters followed by `-SRC_` followed by one or more digits:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

pattern = re.compile(r"UID_(\w+)\-SRC_\d+")
id = soup.find("div", id=pattern)["id"]

uid = pattern.match(id).group(1)
print(uid)
```

Here we are using `BeautifulSoup` and searching for an [`id` attribute value to match a specific regular expression](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression). It contains a [saving group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#grouping) `(\w+)` that helps us to extract the UID value.

Comment: It worked thankyou so much for taking the time out to help me. And opening my eyes towards the use of regex

Answer (score 0):

you can use **.get** method and scrape the tag names easily,

in your question;

`soup.get('id')`

of course, if there are many **id** tags exist, you need to use more specific tags with **find** or **find_all** method before using the **.get**